# SAS RANDOM SAMPLING, WITH GROUP SIZE

Tags: select, random, sas, proc, survey

I have a data set with accounts and its attribute (there are 9 main attributes).
Each attribute group contains a different amount of account, where 2 groups hold a massively higher amount of accounts. Therefore, when I use PROC SURVEYSELECT, to randomly select 5 accounts per STRATA, and the METHOD=SRS, I get more results from attributes which contain more accounts. 
How can I correct that? how can I make SAS consider the group's volume when sampling?

The above mentioned code:

```
PROC SURVEYSELECT DATA=FINAL_RANDOM OUT=FINAL_RANDOM_1 NOPRINT 
     METHOD=srs
     SAMPSIZE = 5 
     SELECTALL;
     STRATA Account_Branch_Id ; 
RUN;
```

Comment: `SAMPSIZE=5` will result in 5 samples per strata, so I'm not sure why you state *"I get more results from attributes which contain more accounts"*

Comment: lets say, for example, that I have 5 attribute groups: (1) with 50,000 accounts (2) with 30,000 accounts and (3) with 8,000 accounts (4) with 9,000 accounts (5) with 3,000 accounts. All together I have 100,000 accounts as a whole. The when I execute PROC SERVEYSELECT, I get 3 accounts from attribute (1) and 2 accounts from attribute (4), instead of getting one of each (for example). Further more, in reality I have 9 attribute groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example generated data with two strata (branches) each containing 35% of all the accounts and the other 7 strata containing the remaining 30% of account equally distributed.

The code in the question **does** select 5 samples from each strata (`branch_id`), and randomly over attribute (`risk`).

I am not so good at `SurverySelect` to say you can't select 'evenly' over `risk` within `strata` --  but if able to do so, you will need to specify a `METHOD=` other than `SRS`

**Example**

```
data have;
  call streaminit (123);
  do account_id = 1 to 100000;
    x = rand('uniform');
    select;
      when (x>.65) branch_id = 1;
      when (x>.30) branch_id = 2;
      otherwise branch_id = 3 + floor(rand('uniform',7));
    end;

    open_date = round(rand('uniform', today())); format open_date yymmdd10.;
    balance = round(rand('uniform',1e6)); format balance dollar9.;

    if branch_id = 7 then do;
      open_date = round(rand('uniform', 4000));
      balance = 5e5 + round(rand('uniform',5e5)); format balance dollar9.;
    end;

    select (branch_id);
      when (1) risk = ceil(rand('normal',5,1));
      when (5) risk = ceil(rand('uniform', 2)) * 2;
      when (6) risk = 3 + ceil(rand('uniform', 4));
      when (9) risk = 4 + ceil(rand('uniform', 5));
      otherwise risk = ceil(rand('uniform', 9));
    end;

    output;
  end;
  drop x;
run;

proc sort data=have;
  by branch_id account_id;
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  title "Original risk distribution by branch";
  class branch_id risk;
  table branch_id='', risk * n='' * format=comma9. * [s=[width=1cm]] / box='branch_id';
run;
```

`* survery select;`

```
PROC SURVEYSELECT NOPRINT DATA=have OUT=want
     METHOD=srs
     SAMPSIZE = 5 
     SELECTALL
;
     STRATA Branch_Id ; 
RUN;

proc sql;
  create table sample_classes_with_zeros as
  select class.branch_id, class.risk,
    case when sample.risk then 1 else 0 end as z
  from (
    select distinct branch_id, risk from have 
  ) as class
  left join sample 
  on class.branch_id = sample.branch_id
   & class.risk = sample.risk
  ;

proc tabulate data=sample_classes_with_zeros;
  title "A SurveySelect SRS SAMPSIZE=5 sampling, risk distribution by branch";
  class branch_id risk;
  var z;
  table branch_id='', risk * z='' * sum='' * f=comma9. * [s=[width=1cm textalign=center]] / box='branch_id';
run;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you wrote is correct and understood, BUT - you still have no indication that (for example) in branch 1, 4 accounts are from attribute (2) and 1 account from attribute (3). I need it to give me 1 of each attribute, per branch, knowing that I have a total of 9 attributes. and not, in worst case scenario, 5 accounts from the same attribute.

Comment: So, by attributes, do you mean additional variables, such as the open_date, balance (in the example data generator) and perhaps other 'ranky' or discrete kinds of variables, as might be found in 'fantasy banking' such as account_type, overdraw_risk_level, last_survey_overall_satisfaction_level, associated_account_count, age_bracket, etc... ?

Comment: YES! think of it as 9 risk levels; so the solution given here, could possibly gives me (again, for example) a branch, with 5 accounts (so far so good), but from the same risk level, ignoring the fact that there are 9 different levels. I need SAS to acknowledge that there are 9 risk levels , and give me 5 accounts from 5 different levels. In case a specific (or many) branches only have accounts from 4 risk levels (possible and plausible)  then give me 4 accounts from 4 different risk levels and another one from one of the same risk levels. I hope I am clear....thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite getting your point, if you use Sample Size as number of rows, you'll get exact number of rows by your strata [Random Sample node in SAS Guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d363H.png)

And the same goes for your code,

```
PROC SURVEYSELECT DATA=*YOURDATASET* OUT=DATA 
 METHOD=srs
 SAMPSIZE = 5 
 SELECTALL;
 STRATA *YOUR_STRATA_VARIABLE*; 
RUN;
```

Difference between N number of observations (in 'Random Sample' node in SAS Guide) and SAMPSIZE (in the code) is that **N** gives you *total number of observations*, while **SAMPSIZE** gives you *number per strata variable*.

Comment: You are missing one column, to fully understand my problem: if you add another column named 'attribute' which goes from 1-9, you could see from which attribute did each account arrive, and thus resulting in 5 accounts PER branch, but (statistically) all from the same attribute.